# Differences between Django on AppEngine and Django on my Linux Server?

Tags: django, djangoappengine

I am a Django beginner, and I want to make this tutorial as exercise: http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2009/05/28/django-based-blog-on-google-app-engine-tutorial-part-1

The thing is that this tutorial is for AppEngine, but I want to do the tutorial in my Linux Development machine using a common database.

I have noticed that there are few differences:

In the Models:

```
from appengine_django.models import BaseModel
from google.appengine.ext import db

class BlogPost(BaseModel):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    uri = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    teaser = db.TextProperty()
    teaser_html = db.TextProperty()
    content = db.TextProperty()
    content_html = db.TextProperty()
    tags = db.StringProperty()
```

These imports are different:

```
from appengine_django.models import BaseModel
from google.appengine.ext import db
```

If I change this by:

```
from django.db import models
```

It will work?

Then I noticed one more reference to AppEngine:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms
```

What imports should I use here to make this compatible with my Django on my Linux development server?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppEngine is not Django. There are ways of getting Django to work (more or less) on AppEngine, but that tutorial is specifically for AppEngine, not Django.

If you want to learn Django, do a Django tutorial. There are enough out there on the web.